# Execute ExtendScript in InDesign from AppleScript

Tags: applescript, adobe-indesign, extendscript

I can use AppleScript to send ExtendScript to **Photoshop** and get back the result:

This sends "2" to stdout:

```
tell application "Adobe Photoshop CC 2017"
    do javascript "var x = 2; x"
end tell
```

I get a syntax error when I try the same thing for InDesign 2015:

This results in a syntax error: `Expected end of line but found application constant or consideration.`

```
tell application "Adobe InDesign CC 2015"
    do javascript "var x = 2; x"
end tell
```

This similar code, using `script` instead of `javascript` does slightly better, resulting in this error message: `Adobe InDesign CC 2015 got an error: A identifier can’t go after this identifier.`

```
tell application "Adobe InDesign CC 2015"
    do script "var x = 2; x"
end tell
```

Any suggestions for getting this to work?

Comment: Does this thread help?  It's for After Effects, but checkout the last reply and see if it applies to you: https://forums.adobe.com/thread/973002

Comment: What if you use the last method on this page (with more modern modifications) http://macscripter.net/viewtopic.php?id=15506 and just do `x = 2;`? What happens?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main difference is that "do script" is a specific command of the InDesign Scripting model in Applescript so its syntax is specific.

```js
set myJavaScript to "var x = 2; x"
do script myJavaScript language javascript
```